# Does minimized RDP client consume traffic?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm connecting with RDP on a remote site with paid internet traffic. I'd like to consume as little bandwidth as possible. Would minimizing an RDP client while doing lengthy unattended operations on the reomte desktop help me? (considering disconnect is a bad option)

I'm using an RDP client distributed with Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

It does consume bandwidth, but next to nothing - the only time you will notice it is if you have enabled sound forwarding or drive mapping - and are actually transferring files / listening to sound.

Comment: No sound or drive forwarding. A movie is playing on the remote side. Does your answer apply to this situation?

Comment: In all honesty, I am not sure - the best thing you can do is to fire up wireshark or any network monitoring tool and measure. If I have some spare time in the next few days, I will try to do this for you - I have a very busy schedule so I can't promise I will have time.... but, my guess would be no, other than the standard keep alive packet that gets sent anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with windows 7 default RDP client mstsc.exe and found that visual changes on the remote screen are not received when the client minimized. So the answer is, minimizing window of the client also minimizes consumed network bandwidth.